# Is there a way of displaying a full list of errors when checking in pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015

I'm currently going through checking in changes I have made to my code. There are well over 100 files which have been changed, and I am repetitively getting this error for various files.

> Could not find file '[File Path]'.

While I can understand the reasoning for the error, and I know on how I can fix it, **how would I display all files which are throwing this type of error when checking in?** Consider it to resolving merge conflicts, you would be given a list of files which require attention, you can easily see multiple and deal with them. Unfortunately while checking in changes, it only displays on error at a time.

The current process I am going through is Check In > Error Thrown > Fix Error and repeat. It would be so much more faster to be able to see all affected files and deal with them unlike the way I am currently doing.

I am using TFS 2015 on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing to fix this? Generally you see this when you've deleted files outside of Visual Studio and TFVC doesn't know of it.

Comment: @virusstorm Yeah - that's what's has happened. I'm just undoing all of the pending changes. Nearly all of them have either been renamed, moved or simply no-longer exist.

Comment: If you queue a local build, are you able to see the errors?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good solution (at least not one I'm aware of) to the problem you are facing. Typically in these situations, I recommend to people to backup your changes to another folder and undo your changes in your working copy. From there copy back in the files you care about and if you renamed or delete files, make sure you do it through Visual Studio in either the solution explorer (provided your solution is correctly connected to version control) or in the source control explorer.

Another option is to try and reconcile the changes in source control explorer. You can use the `tf` command line tool to get a list of pending changes. Running `tf status` at the root of your workspace will give you a list of pending changes. You can then compare the output with what you have locally in the file explorer. Any files that need to be renamed or deleted should be done in the source control explorer.

As a side note, when using TFVC you should always do all of your rename and deletes through source control explorer to avoid this issue. Also, try to limit the number of changes you make between commits. Having over 100 files changed in one commit will quickly get you into a situation like you are in. Smaller, incremental commits are always preferred over large sweeping changes.